# React Router: Changing components and routes by button

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In a React application, there is a page with 2 buttons. Each button renders a different component, however, the route/URL doesn't change. How can I change the route, only changing the grey area? and How can I change the state if the user goes directly to the URL?

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/embed/elastic-fog-7hqk9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You are installing `react-router-dom`, but you don't use it. Here is an example you can follow https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: so what you suggest me is add the /component1 and /component2 in the routes.js file, so I can go there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Switch`, it will render your component in case it matched the URL. Here is an example:

```
<Container>
  <Header />    // this will render in all cases (Fixed here for example)
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/component1" component={Component1} />
    <Route exact path="/component2" component={Component2} />
  </Switch>
</Container>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I was overthinking the solution, and forget the trivial.